# IO NoSuchElementException thrown unless document is modifed when using relative path

Tags: java, io

I am trying to read some numbers in a file that looks something like this:

TestFile.txt:

```
4
900 1100
1000 1200
400 1100
5000 5100
```

Main:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    private static int[][] data;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

        File file = new File("TestFile.txt");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        int length = scanner.nextInt();

        data = new int[length][2];

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            data[i][0] = scanner.nextInt(); //throws exception here
            System.out.print( data[i][0] + " ");
            data[i][1] = scanner.nextInt(); 
            System.out.print( data[i][1] + "\n");
        }


        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

If I run this, it works fine.  However, If I try to run it again, it gives me `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.  If I modify the file, (by adding a space or something) the program works again.

Why is this happening?  (and also explain what I can do to fix this, because it is getting annoying having to resave the file again and again.)

I'm running it on net beans, if you are wondering.

Edit:

After doing some experimenting, I've noticed that this problem only appears if I give it a relative path instead of an absolute path.  I originally added the file through the netbeans project properties and added the file as an argument.  Maybe this is part of the problem?  Is there a way to keep the relative path, but make the problem disappear?

Comment: please give us a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @MikeNakis Is it too long or does it not work?

Comment: it is not complete, i.e. not *self contained*.  If you wrap it in `main()` (and add a couple of `#include`s) it will be.  But then I highly doubt that the code above wrapped in `main()` exhibits the behaviour you are describing.  Also keep in mind you can use ideone.com.

Comment: The code looks fine and I cannot reproduce this.  What do you mean by "run it again"?  The behavior sounds like the input file was never closed and you are attempting to read off the end of the file.  You are going to have to describe exactly what you're doing in more detail.

Comment: @JimGarrison I go into the text file, add like a space or something and then save it.  Then I press the run button that netbeans gives me, and the code does not throw an exception.  I don't really know much about IO, but I closed the scanner.  Do I have to do something else too?

Comment: @MikeNakis I've wrapped the code in main, and added the imports.

Comment: Your code looks fine, and you should not be having the issue that you are having.  Something else is causing your problem, but it is missing from the picture, so I cannot tell what the problem is.

Comment: (I should mention, though, that the code is not complete, and you cannot possibly be using this exact code, because it would not compile, as it is missing a closing curly bracket.  The point of providing us with an SSCCE is that the SSCCE must *compile and run* and when you run it, it must exhibit *the problem that you are having*.)

Comment: @MikeNakis, sorry, I messed that up when I wrapped the code.   I omitted main() originally for brevity.  I tested my code before I posted and it complied fine, and still gave me the problem.